# Why the count isn't rendered on the browser?

Tags: reactjs

[image: react component]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Product extends Component {
    state = { 
        name: "Burger",
        count: 3,
        imgUrl: "logo192.png"
     }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <img src={this.state.imgUrl} alt="" />
                <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.name}</span>
                <span className="badge badge-warning m-2">{this.state.count}</span>
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default Product;
```

[image: react app]

I'm trying to show the count value in the state in the render() method using {this.state.count} but it doesn't appear on the browser.

Comment: Can you show the definition of classes badge badge-warning m-2 ?  Or, better: change that span in a H1 without any classes and see if the count is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code snippet I see your count is displayed. My suggestion would check the span inside your elements in the chrome's inspector tool. If the span is there and has the value 3 inside of it then it would be a styling issue from `className="badge badge-warning m-2"`

Comment: I installed bootstrap, I didn't define these classes.